# Problem doing reverse polish notation (Java)

Tags: java

One of the problems that im finding is that i cant manage to compare the +,-,*,/  is there any other way?  THx for the help

CODE:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question2 {

    public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    double array[] = new double[20];

    System.out.print("Enter sum: ");
    String sum = scan.nextLine();

    getValue(sum, array, 0);

    System.out.print(array[0]);
    }


    public static void getValue(String input, double array[], int poi){
     int counter = 0;
     char nextValue = ' ';
     String value = "";
     double num = 0;
     boolean checkDub = true;

        do{
            value = value + input.charAt(counter);

            counter ++;     
            nextValue = input.charAt(counter);   
        }while(nextValue != ' ');

     try {num = Integer.parseInt(value);}
     catch (Exception e) {
      checkDub = false;

      double l2 = array[poi];
      poi--;

      double l1 = array[poi];

      if(value.equals("+")){ array[poi] =  l1 + l2;} // <--- comparing problem?
      else if(value.equals("-")){ array[poi] =  l1 - l2;}
      else if(value.equals("*")){ array[poi] =  l1 * l2;}
      else if(value.equals("/")){ array[poi] =  l1 / l2;}
      else{System.out.println("Error");}

    }
        if(checkDub = true){
        array[poi] = num;}

        String nextInput = input.substring(counter);
        getValue(nextInput, array, poi + 1);


    }

}
```

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure your problem is that you're not stripping off leading space characters. For example, if your input is `"2 2 + "`, then at the third invocation your input is `" + "`, and value gets `" +"`. That fails your equality check with `"+"`. Meanwhile, `parseInt` cheerfully strips leading whitespace.

Your code will also throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException if your input is not terminated by a space. Further, you won't handle more complex expressions like `"1 2 + 3 +"` because you *don't* do recursive call after evaluating the first one. (Hint: you should return when you've consumed all tokens from the input).

Style points (not bugs): you should use indexOf to find the space (or, even better, split). The recursive tail call should really be a loop (for very long inputs, you might cause a StackOverflowError). You don't need to have a boolean checkDub - rather, you can place the body of `if (checkDub == true)` inside the `try` (after the `parseInt`). But that you'd probably want to refactor anyway if you're using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Try printing out what `value` contains at the point where you think that there is a problem with comparison.
2. Try solving the problem in an OO way; e.g. change the `getValue` method to be non-static, and use instance variables for the state.
3. You cannot use `=` to compare values.  Use `==` instead.  Also `a == true` is equivalent to `a`.